# Login in to the classic mode still runs Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, applet

yeah yeah I know I should log out and select Ubuntu Classic when I want to log back in but that doesn't work!
I can still see the unity launcher and none of my applets work!!!
what is the problem here?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Maybe you have the same error I am having since yesterday: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48295/unable-to-log-into-gnome-desktop

Comment: nope, that's not my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is odd , this should be disabled when you choose The Ubuntu Classic.

But You can disable Unity, by using `CCSM` : [Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

Go to desktop --> Ubuntu Unity plugin --> Uncheck as shown.
[image]

Comment: Glad to help, anytime :)